# I watched porn and masturbated twice in ramadan How do I ask for forgivness? Will Allah forgive my sins? What do I have to do to make up for this fast

Tags: fiqh, ramadan, forgiveness, tawba, masturbation

I watched porn and masturbated twice in the same day this ramadan.
How do I ask for forgivness?
Will Allah forgive my sins?
What do I have to do to make up for this fast

Answer (score 0):

If you masturbated while fasting, yes you will have to make up your fasts.
Ejaculation & sexual intimacy breaks your fast.

As for sinning and needing repentance.

**Yes.** Allah will forgive you.
It doesn’t matter how big of a sin is, repent.
Don’t underestimate the mercy of Allah.
It’s so grand that if you were to deliberately sin, disobey Him, he still gives you the luxuries you need to live. There is not a single thing He will not forgive. But you have to make that choice to repent from that haram deed.