# Watching porn in ramadan day

Tags: kaffarah

I am asking about the kafara for watching porn in ramadan day. Ehat is it ? I know I have commited a bad sin but i ask god to fogive me. Please pray for me

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/67940/i-watched-porn-and-masturbated-twice-in-ramadan-how-do-i-ask-for-forgivness-wil?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C59.6690

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, watching porn doesn't break fast unless you do istimna and ejaculate.